# How to provide type safety in C# "enum keys - properties" relation like in TypeScript advanced types

Tags: c#, typescript, types

I write in C# and TypeScript and have noticed that sometimes cannot do in C# some things. I want to check users permissions, and in C# its going bad - with reflection and repeating `Permission` keys in `Configuration` properties, whereas in TypeScript its have done easily. Is there a way to get rid off C# version's disadvantages?

**C#**

```
public enum Permission { download, upload }

public class User
{
    public string[] Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public PermissionGroupsSection PermissionGroups { get; set; }
    public class PermissionGroupsSection
    {
        public string Download { get; set; }
        public string Upload { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly Configuration config;
    public Service(Configuration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void Check(User user, Permission permission)
    {
        string group = typeof(Configuration.PermissionGroupsSection)
            .GetProperty(permission.ToString())
            .GetValue(config.PermissionGroups) as string;
        if (!user.Groups.Contains(group))
            throw new Exception("Access denied");
    }

    public void DownloadFile(User user, string fileName)
    {
        Check(user, Permission.download);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName + " downloaded!");
    }
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
type Permission = "download" | "upload";

interface IUser {
    groups: string[];
}

interface IConfiguration {
    permissionGroups: { [key in Permission]: string };
}

let config: IConfiguration = JSON.parse(`
    "permissionGroups": {
        "download": "Everyone",
        "upload": "RegisteredUsers"
    }
`);

function check(user: IUser, permission: Permission) {
    if (!user.groups.includes(config.permissionGroups[permission]))
        throw "Access denied";
}

function downloadFile(user: IUser, fileName: string) {
    check(user, "download");
    alert(fileName + " downloaded!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that this is a disadvantage of C#, it's just that you have to approach the languages differently. Typescript is still very much a dynamic language, and C# is very much a static language (although lines are starting to get a little blurry...).

When I have a problem like this, I always ask myself what the best data structures are for the needs of the code.

In your case, you need to be able to define permission groups against a set of known actions. In C#, the closest thing to a JSON object you can query by key is a dictionary. So I would declare my permissions something like:

```
IDictionary<Permission, string> PermissionGroups = new Dictionary<Permission, string>
{
  { Permission.download, "Everyone" },
  { Permission.upload, "RegisteredUsers" }
};
```

I would say this is now synonymous with the typescript version, as it means your Check method can look like:

```
public void Check(User user, Permission permission)
{
  if (!user.Groups.Contains(PermissionGroups[permission]))
    throw new Exception("Access denied");
}
```

Your code implies that this comes from your config file, in which case this is just creating a new problem elsewhere.

I am purposefully avoiding the discussion about the possible ways to do role-based security.

Comment: I don't think that such a problem as mapping json config file to Dictionary with enum keys must be treated separately. Ugly solution solves task, and code with enum (though it is right and C#-way) doesn't.

Comment: I would say that how you store your permissions in memory, and how they are stored on disk (config file, for example) are absolutely different concerns, and the two concerns shouldn't necessarily be mixed up in the same code. And how they are stored on disk shouldn't determine how you structure your in-memory data.

Comment: Hmm, may be you right in common case, but this is configuration template, that it's purpose to provide connection between two concerns